# Busca sem retornar dados PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

A minha variável esta  sendo passada porem no processo de filtro sempre não esta retornando nada.

```
try 
{
   $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
   if (!empty($keyword)) 
   {

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 
         titulo LIKE :keyword OR conteudo LIKE :keyword ORDER BY Nid";

       $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

       $likekeyword = "%".$keyword."%";
       $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $likekeyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

   } 
   else 
   {
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE 1 ORDER BY Nid ";
       $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   }

   $stmt->execute();
```

tentei `(titulo LIKE :termo) OR ...`

Atualizado o estranho e que o resultado do `if empty` em branco ta funcionando o que me leva a crer que e na parte de consulta mesmo

Comment: O problema está na consulta e não no php. A ideia é buscar por `%:key%` ? faz um sqlfiddle e coloca o link na pergunta e as consultas que não funcionaram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o seu problema se resolva dessa maneira:

```
try {
     $termo = trim($_GET["termo"]);
      if (!empty($termo)) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE :termo OR conteudo LIKE :termo ORDER BY Nid";
$stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

$likeTermo = "%".$termo."%";
$stmt->bindParam(':termo', $likeTermo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
...
```

**Considere estas diferenças:**

> **`PDOStatement::bindValue()`** -> A variável está vinculada à referência e só será avaliada no momento em que o `PDOStatement::execute()` for chamado. E neste caso, só é aceito valores como argumento.

Se você usar `$stmt->bindValue(":termo", $termo);`.

O valor deverá existir obrigatoriamente, senão ocorrerá um erro.

> **`PDOStatement::bindParam()`** -> Já neste caso, ​​o argumento esperado é uma referência (variável ou constante) e não pode ser um tipo primitivo como uma string ou número solto, retorno de função ou método.

Exemplos inválidos:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':termo', 10); // Inválido
$stmt->bindParam(':termo', getValue()); // Inválido
```

Comment: infelizmente nao continua retornando nada, ja havia tentado algo assim antes, testei denovo pra ter certeza porem o resultado e o mesmo

Comment: quanto a diferenca do param e value entendi , obrigado pela dica porem ainda continua sem os resultados, atualizei o codigo

Comment: talvez o problema não esteja neste trecho. E sim na saída, o que acontece quando você dá um `var_dump($stmt->execute())` ?

Comment: E o que acontece quando vc executa essa query com o termo direto no workbench ou phpmyadmin?

Comment: bool(true)  retorna verdadeiro , exibe a mensagem que programei ( nenhuma busca foi encontrada)  e tenho so nos titulos 3 resultados das palavras que busquei

Comment: quando você executa: `SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE '%a%' OR conteudo LIKE '%a%' ORDER BY Nid` no workbench, o que retorna?

Comment: rapaz executei o seguinte: SELECT *
FROM `noticias`
WHERE titulo LIKE audio
OR conteudo LIKE audio
ORDER BY Nid
LIMIT 0 , 30 

e o resultado foi incrivel

http://prntscr.com/8ow940  

 Pode isso arnaldo?...

Comment: qualquer coisa veja, se os parâmetros estão sendo processados: `$stmt->debugDumpParams();` ao final do `...->execute()`

Comment: SQL: [88] SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE :keyword OR conteudo LIKE :keyword ORDER BY Nid Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :keyword paramno=-1 name=[8] ":keyword" is_param=1 param_type=2  resultado .. mais como to começando em pdo nem sei do que ta falando, esses param são as variaveis? ou campos?

Comment: Olha aqui do que se trata, é para você verificar sua query: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Comment: rapaz descobri uma coisa se eu pesquiso por "a" ele me retorna o resultado cujo a primeira letra do conteudo é "a" . me parece estar so verificando a primeira palavra

Comment: Quando você usa like, o símbolo % representa qualquer ocorrência, se estiver á esquerda (%abc) qualquer ocorrência que comece com  "abc", na direita usando abc%, significa qualquer ocorrência que termine com "abc". também pode usar _  como curinga de caráter único. Use os curingas para fazer a consulta. a propósito, essa consulta que você fez tratando `...LIKE audio ...` a palavra audio, sem aspas não é um termo de pesquisa, ele entra como um valor "null".

Answer (score 1):

Caro amigo, não sei se existem aí mais erros, mas, deste bocado de código que aí tens, vejo apenas uma irregularidade capaz de causar este problema, que é o número de parâmetros vinculados através do *bindParam*. Na tua consulta *SQL* foste bem específico fornecendo *dois placeholders*, com os nomes *:titulo* e *:conteúdo*, porém durante a parte em que vinculavas os valores desses respectivos *placeholders*, passaste apenas um.

Veja algumas correções que apliquei ao teu script:

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

// Valores Extrnos
$key = isset($_GET["keyword"]) ? trim( (string) $_GET["keyword"]) : NULL;

// Conectar PDO
try{
        
    $opc = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=banco_de_dados;", "root", "", $opc);    
    
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE :titulo OR conteudo LIKE :conteudo ORDER BY id ASC";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE titulo LIKE :titulo OR conteudo LIKE :conteudo ORDER BY Nid";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    
    $key = "%" . $key . "%";    
    
    $stmt->bindParam(":titulo", $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
    $stmt->bindParam(":conteudo", $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    // Capturar exceção, se haver uma
    } catch(PDOException $e){                
    echo "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();    
}

// Resultados
if(isset($stmt)){
    while($linhas = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        echo  $linhas->titulo . "<br/>";    
        echo  $linhas->conteudo. "<br/>";
    }    
}

?>
```

**NOTA:** Trabalhar com o `PDO`, requer alguns cuidados, e reparei também que nesta parte do teu script, tens o `try`, mas não vi a parte `catch` onde deve-se capturar a exceção, caso haja alguma.

---

## Referências:

[PDO::bindParam - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#example-1006)

[Exceptions - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

[Catch - PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.catch.php)